# Tracing system calls is slow on a KVM VPS?

Tags: vps, kvm-virtualization, strace

I run a website on a KVM VPS and I noticed that processes appear to run extremely slowly when being traced. For example, I ran `ls` on my home directory, which contains 72 files and directories.

With `strace`:

```
real    0m13.591s
user    0m0.024s
sys     0m6.972s
```

No particular system call is especially slow, but there is a noticeable (~0.1 s) pause after each one in the `strace` output.

Without `strace`:

```
real    0m0.101s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.068s
```

I'm not sure whether this is related, but recursively removing large directories is also very slow. For example, I used

```
rsync -av `mktemp -d`/ dir
```

and it made extremely slow progress, removing only about 200 files per second. (That's slow, right?)

Is this a bug in KVM? Is there any way I could get my hosting company to fix it?

Comment: It's hard to say.  Are you using the virtio drivers?  This could easily be a machine on a host with high load, but it could also be issues with the guest.  Does `top` show high steal time?  Run `ioping` against the drive for awhile, see if the numbers are consistent

Comment: @devicenull yep, it's using virtio. `ioping` numbers don't seem very consistent; avg is 67.2 ms but maybe one in ten requests it's as high as 200 ms. Steal time appears to be 0.0%.

Comment: Any idea what could be up with the tracing? That's way more important than the slow disk accesses.

Comment: 67ms from ioping is pretty high.  That means it takes at least 67ms to execute any sort of command to the disk.  I wonder if your hosting company has overprovisioned the machines so your guest keeps getting swapped to the (terribly slow) disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I still don't know what the problem was, but rebooting fixed it.